# Mat icon angular complex images

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am new to angular and  just started using mat icons in angular. I have learned to created basic mat icons in angular. But getting confused to make some complex mat icons. For example as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbMQ2.png)

How I can make these using mat icons in angular?

Comment: You can't because they are not part of the material design icons/spec. The available icons are listed [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/). You could include icon-like functionality by using a small transparent PNG in your app or something similar.

Comment: How can I do that using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

So no one answered this question, so I myself will try to answer it.As per available material  documents only those mat icons are available for use. We cannot modify them as per our need but we can use them in combination with css and bootstrap.

PS::You can register svg images to be used as material icons

Comment: This isn’t correct. You can register svg images to be used as material icons.